# Lining up decimal points using System.out.printf

Tags: java, printf

I am trying to line up my output so my decimal points line up correctly. I am very close to achieving this, but the hundreds place does not line up correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
After day 1 you have $         0.02
After day 2 you have $         0.04
After day 3 you have $         0.08
After day 4 you have $         0.16
After day 5 you have $         0.32
After day 6 you have $         0.64
After day 7 you have $         1.28
After day 8 you have $         2.56
After day 9 you have $         5.12
After day 10 you have $        10.24
After day 11 you have $        20.48
After day 12 you have $        40.96
After day 13 you have $        81.92
After day 14 you have $       163.84
After day 15 you have $       327.68
After day 16 you have $       655.36
After day 17 you have $     1,310.72
After day 18 you have $     2,621.44
After day 19 you have $     5,242.88
After day 20 you have $    10,485.76
After day 21 you have $    20,971.52
After day 22 you have $    41,943.04
After day 23 you have $    83,886.08
After day 24 you have $   167,772.16
After day 25 you have $   335,544.32
After day 26 you have $   671,088.64
After day 27 you have $ 1,342,177.28
After day 28 you have $ 2,684,354.56
After day 29 you have $ 5,368,709.12
After day 30 you have $10,737,418.24
```

My code is System.out.printf("After day %d you have $%,13.2f\n", day, money);

Comment: Try `%2d`, to right-align the day number too.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("After day %2d you have $%,13.2f\n", day, money);
```

%2d will right indent the number, and will take 2 charater space.